# CallList inside NewList OpenGL

Tags: c#, list, opengl, opentk

I need to display objects on the screen using OpenGL. I started with displaying one of them constantly using `GL.CallList`.

The problem is that now I need to display more than just one object. The number of objects is unknown, and they are added on the go while the program is running. So I can't prepare just the right number of lists to display.

My solution was to switch between two lists, displaying one of them at the time, and switching them after adding new object. Here is the code which is used after adding another object to display:

```
 if (pierwszy == true)
            {
                obiektrys = GL.GenLists(1);
                obiektrys2 = GL.GenLists(1);
                zmieniacz_list = 1;
            }

            if (zmieniacz_list == 1)
            {
                GL.NewList(obiektrys, ListMode.CompileAndExecute);
                GL.CallList(obiektrys2);
                if (comboBox6.SelectedItem.ToString() == "koło")
                    rysuj_cylinder(0, 0, r / 5, wys / 5);
                else if (comboBox6.SelectedItem.ToString() == "prostokąt")
                    rysuj_szescian(0, 0, a / 5, b / 5, wys / 5);
                GL.EndList();
                zmieniacz_list = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                GL.NewList(obiektrys2, ListMode.CompileAndExecute);
                GL.CallList(obiektrys);
                if (comboBox6.SelectedItem.ToString() == "koło")
                    rysuj_cylinder(0, 0, r / 5, wys / 5);
                else if (comboBox6.SelectedItem.ToString() == "prostokąt")
                    rysuj_szescian(0, 0, a / 5, b / 5, wys / 5);
                GL.EndList();
                //GL.NewList(obiektrys, ListMode.CompileAndExecute);
                //GL.CallList(obiektrys2);
                //GL.EndList();
                zmieniacz_list = 1;
            }
            wysakt += (wys/5);
            pierwszy = false;
```

And here is the code which is displaying objects continously on the screen:

```
public void obrot()
    {
        Matrix4 perspective = Matrix4.Perspective(fov, w / h, 1, 10 * maxz);
        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
        GL.LoadMatrix(ref perspective);

        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);
        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
        GL.Translate(transx, transy, 0);
        GL.Rotate(rotx, 1, 0, 0);
        GL.Rotate(roty, 0, 1, 0);
        GL.Rotate(rotz, 0, 0, 1);
        GL.CallList(osierys);
        if (pokaz == 1)
        {
            GL.CallList(obiektrys);
            GL.CallList(obiektrys2);
        }
        GL.CallList(wykres);

        glControl1.SwapBuffers();
        rotx = 0;
        roty = 0;
        rotz = 0;
        transx = 0;
        transy = 0;
    }
```

The effect is that only last 2 object are displayed, "older" objects are "forgotten".

My question is: Is calling `CallList` inside `NewList` invalid, or is the problem somewhere else?

Comment: In other words; can you nest calllists?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `CallList` inside of `NewList`. However, based on your code, it does not behave the way you understood.

If you use `CallList` for display list B inside of a display list A, what becomes part of display list A is the actual `CallList` call for B, not the current content of B. In other words, you could say that B is inserted into A "by reference", not "by value".

For example, with somewhat symbolic notation, if you do the following:

```
NewList(A);
CallList(B);
EndList();
```

A now contains instructions to execute list B. When you call A at this point:

```
CallList(A);
```

it will render the current content of B.

But if you modify B:

```
NewList(B);
// drawing commands
EndList();
```

and then call A again:

```
CallList(A);
```

this will now use the new content of B, since calling A will always use the current content of B.

This means that your scheme will not work. Since, after a couple of steps, you call A inside B as well as B inside A, you basically have an infinite recursion between the two. When you call A, this calls B, which calls A, which calls B, ... The spec says about this:

> To avoid the possibility of infinite recursion resulting from display lists calling one another, an implementation dependent limit is placed on the nesting level of display lists during display list execution. This limit must be at least 64.

So the implementation prevented an endless loop, but the whole thing will definitely not work as you intended.

If you want to stick with display lists, the most straightforward approach is probably that you create a new display list for each object, and then call all of them at once with a `glCallLists()` call, which takes an array of display lists as an argument.

You should be aware that display lists have been obsolete for about 15 years, and are not part of newer OpenGL versions anymore. If you write new code, I would recommend to look into newer drawing methods, which involve vertex buffers.